Fastest conversion of numpy array in pyodide
Let's say I use Pyodide, from Javascript, to declare a numpy array in Python:
pyodide.runPython(`a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)`)

Now I want to load the same data into a Javascript Uint8Array, as quickly as possible. How should I do that? In particular, is there a way to create a Uint8Array which points to the exact same bytes as a in memory, avoiding all copying costs?
